# Is PostBQP experimentally relevant?

Tags: experimental-realization, complexity-theory, postbqp

Far from my expertise, but sheer curiosity. I've read that [PostBQP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostBQP) ("*a complexity class consisting of all of the computational problems solvable in polynomial time on a quantum Turing machine **with postselection** and bounded error*") is very powerful.  Still, I don't understand the practical sense of assuming you can *decide* the value an output qubit takes.

My question: Have post-selection quantum computing experiments been implemented (or is it possible that they will be implemented)? 
(And, if the answer is yes: how does post-selection take place in a way that practically enhances your computing power?)

Comment: I _think_ the answers in the question I linked would answer this question as well. If not, please explain why those answers don't, so that we can clarify this question.

Comment: The question is different... but it turns out that the answers do satisfy my question. Thanks!